# Return data from datareader asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, sqldatareader

I am new to the async stuff and am having a lot of problems trying to get this to work:

I am trying to load a large result set from SQL what I want to have happen is when I run the code below:

```
public async override IEnumerable<DataResult> Read()
{
    using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(Options.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        await objConn.OpenAsync();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(Options.SqlText, objConn);
        SqlDataReader reader = await comm.ExecuteReaderAsync();

        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            yield return new DataResult { Reader = reader };
    }
}
```

Producer code:

```
BlockingCollection<DataResult> DataCollection = new BlockingCollection<DataResult>();

var producer = new Producer<DataResult>(() =>
{
    using (var sequenceEnum = sourceEngine.Read().GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (sequenceEnum.MoveNext())
            return sequenceEnum.Current;
    }
    return null;
}, DataCollection);
producer.Start();
```

That it returns the data as it reads it in record by record to a producer which will store this data into a `BlockingCollection` for the consumer to consume.

How can I get this code to work for what I am expecting it to do?

Comment: Can you post any code for the blocking collection or producer?

Comment: do you wan't to get a stream of DataResult and add it to a blocking collection ?

Comment: Yes I want when the data is read record by record to be returned to the producer to add it to the BlockingCollection.

Comment: For one, type `SqlDataReader` needs to be `Task<SqlDataReader>`. `reader.Result` will return once it's finished. What doesn't exist is `reader.ReadAsync()` (see [`SqlDataReader's` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#methodTableToggle)).

Comment: You don't want to return the SqlDataReader itself.  You want to pull the data out of the reader using things like GetInt, GetDouble, GetString, GetFieldValue, ...

Comment: @Pluto There is indeed a reader.ReadAsync().  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.readasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What error/problem are you having with the code you have?

Comment: First problem is i have a compile error: async method must be void or Task. Second issue, is I am not sure if I am doing this the correct way and looking for advice for someone if they know a better way to do this.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the docs for .NET 4 instead of 4.5+

Answer (score 3):

Your `Read` signature is not asynchronous:

```
public override IEnumerable<DataResult> Read();
```

Any implementation of this method must be synchronous. So you could implement it just using `yield` and not using `async`/`await` at all.

If you want it to be asynchronous, change `Read` to `ReadAsync`:

```
public override Task<IEnumerable<DataResult>> ReadAsync();
```

which you can implement by (asynchronously) reading into a list, and then returning that list.

However, if what you really want is an *asynchronous sequence* (handling each piece of data as it comes in), then you should use Rx:

```
public override IObservable<DataResult> Read();
```

Comment: that's what i was aiming for as well.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary I am not sure how I would set that up. Do you have a code sample?

Comment: @Paul: How to set what up? You mean the Rx option?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure how I would use the Rx option with the return yield.

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately can't `yield` from an `async` method. Marking it as `async`, you need to return `void`, `Task` or `Task<T>` and that prevents any `yield` to be made in the method body.

You could maybe return `IEnumerable<Task<T>>`, returning everything that you were previously awaiting instead of using `await` (you won't be able to use `async`/`await` in this method anymore).

Comment: I initially tried to not make the method async but I was having an issue trying to open a sql Connection with a  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>

Comment: Task.StartNew(delegate) will start a new thread, yielding from this is impossible. There is no way of doing what you are asking, in its current form. you will need to modify the return type in some way.